# Parse csv containing array in one column in Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, csv

We have a Python script that creates a csv file of enterprise data. One part of the enterprise data is a list of nacecodes (can be None) looking like this once its written to the csv file `['47299', '8690901', '4729903', '86909']` (It's one cell).

In a second script, this time written in Node.js, we parse the csv file with `papaparse`. We want the nacecodes to be an array but it's a string looking like `"['47299', '8690901', '4729903', '86909']"`

How can we parse this string to an array? I had found a possible solution by using `JSON.parse` but its given me a `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

**Python script**

```
class Enterprise:
    def __init__(self):
        self.enterprise_number = ''
        self.vat_number = ''
        self.nace_codes = set()
        self.tel = ''
        self.mobile = ''
        self.email = ''

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'enterprise_number': self.enterprise_number if self.enterprise_number != '' else None,
            'vat_number': self.vat_number if self.vat_number != '' else None,
            'nace_codes': list(self.nace_codes) if len(self.nace_codes) > 0 else None
            'tel': self.tel if self.tel != '' else None,
            'mobile': self.mobile if self.mobile != '' else None,
            'email': self.email if self.email != '' else None,
        }

def read_data():
    ...

    with open('enterprise_data.csv', 'w',) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['enterprise_number', 'vat_number', 'name', 'nace_codes', 'type_of_enterprise', 'juridical_form', 'start_date', 'county', 'city', 'address', 'postal_code', 'box', 'group_part', 'group_number', 'tel', 'mobile', 'email', 'is_active'])
        
        with open('data/enterprise_insert.csv') as file:
            for line in islice(file, 1, None):

                enterprise = Enterprise()
                line = line.rstrip()

                ...

                formatted_data = enterprise.to_json()
                writer.writerow([formatted_data['enterprise_number'], formatted_data['vat_number'], formatted_data['nace_codes'], formatted_data['tel'], formatted_data['mobile'], formatted_data['email'])
```

**Node.js script**

```
const csvFilePath = 'data/enterprise_data.csv'

const readCSV = async (filePath) => {
    const csvFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const csvData = csvFile.toString();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            transformHeader: header => header.trim(),
            complete: results => {
                console.log('Read', results.data.length, 'records.'); 
                resolve(results.data);
            }
        });
    });
};

const start = async () => {
    try {
        let parsedData = await readCSV(csvFilePath);

        parsedData.map((row, i) => {
            console.log(`${i} | ${row.enterprise_number}`);

            const nace_codes = row.nace_codes ? JSON.parse(row.nace_codes) : '';
            console.log('Parsed value: ', nace_codes);
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Crashed | ${error} `);
    }
}

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that csvData does look like `['47299', '8690901', '4729903', '86909']`.

What’s wrong is that single quote is not accepted in JSON, so JSON.parse throws an error.
To fix this you simply need to replace all occurrences of single quotes by double quotes like so:
`const csvData = csvFile.toString().replaceAll("'", '"')`

Comment: For some reason the read in records by papa parse are decreased from 20551 to 15023